# TinyMCE: Show error message on image uploads

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am able to implement the image upload example found in the documentation of TinyMCE:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/php-upload-handler/

My question is how can I show the user a specific error message when an error occurs? For example, if I upload an invalid file type, it only shows a generic 500 error message like this:

[image]

How can I show a more specific error message to the user like 
"**Invalid extension**"?

Answer (score 1):

Hi need to write your custom images_upload_handler.
In settings add this lines :

```
images_upload_handler : function handler(blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
{
        var valid_extensions = ['png','jpg']
        var ext, extensions;

        extensions = {
          'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
          'image/jpg': 'jpg',
          'image/gif': 'gif',
          'image/png': 'png'
        };
        ext = extensions[blobInfo.blob().type.toLowerCase()] || 'dat';
        //add your extension test here.
        if( valid_extensions.indexOf(ext) == -1){
             failure("Invalid extension");
                return;
        }

        var xhr, formData;

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', settings.url);
        xhr.withCredentials = settings.credentials;

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
        };

        xhr.onerror = function() {
            failure("Image upload failed due to a XHR Transport error. Code: " + xhr.status);
        };

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var json;

            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                failure("HTTP Error: " + xhr.status);
                return;
            }

            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != "string") {
                failure("Invalid JSON: " + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }

            success(pathJoin(settings.basePath, json.location));
        };

        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

        xhr.send(formData);
    }
}
```